# How do I add php to a url?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to re-direct the link below in a javascript function, but I'm unsure how to properly call the php code listed after `?u=`. I've tried the example below and also `inbox.php?u=<?php $log_username; ?>` but it doesn't work. Can somebody guide me in the right direction?

```
window.location.replace("inbox.php?u='.$log_username.'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the `echo` in the php tag. Try with:

```
window.location.replace("inbox.php?u=<?php echo $log_username; ?>");
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the PHP wrappers from the URL.

Try using this:

```
window.location.replace("inbox.php?u=<?=$log_username;?>");
```

You can use `<?= ?>` as a short hand to echo PHP; this is normally used just to echo the one variable like you required in this case.

For further information on PHP Echo check the link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: `<?= ?>` and `<? ?>` are considered bad coding style

Comment: @aastefanov could you provide some evidence to this?

Comment: it's enough to know that `<?= ?>` are removed from PHP 7 and that by default short tags are disabled on a part of the servers:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @aastefanov It seems it was down to personal preference, not bad coding practice for the use of short hand tags. And PHP 7 still being very new, it's only very recently been removed. It may even come back in further iterations

Comment: @aastefanov `<?=` was not removed and is actually a recommended practice, and is available in all PHP installations regardless of configuration. The bad practice has always been `<?`, which is the only tag that depends on the short tags configuration. Perhaps you are thinking of the ASP style tags `<%` and `<%=`, which were removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

header('Location: url');
like
header('Location: inbox.php?u='.$log_username.'');

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.replace("inbox.php?u=<?php echo $log_username; ?>");` (only if you are in an HTML page).